# I want to transfer the image file stored in the oscilloscope to the pc and read it on the pc with Python

Tags: python, python-requests, oscilloscope, pyvisa

I want to transfer images stored in an oscilloscope to a PC with Python.

We have saved the image, but we are inquiring about how to transfer the image file to the PC.

## attach my code

```
inst=rm.open_resource("blahblah::INSTR")

inst.write("*IDN?")
print(inst.read())

# image capture (Success)
inst.write(':DISK:SIM "IMAGE",BMP,SCR,ON,INVERT')

#???????????????????????????????????????????
inst.write(':MMEM:STOR:SCR "myscreen.png"')
inst.write('MMEM:DATA? "C:\\Workspace\\", B')
inst.query("*OPC?")
data=inst.read_raw() ## problem ##


#???????????????????????????????????????????
```

There seems to be a problem in the code between the question marks. 
Especially in the read_raw section time error occurs.

There is also a question as to whether the command is supported.
The user guide does not seem to provide the export command.
I did not find any command when I searched for the word transfer or export.

The oscilloscope I use is the 54831D MOS.

If you know anybody, please help me.
Thank you for reading.

Comment: I am controlling the oscilloscope through the wireless LAN.

The file-related commands for saving to the PC have not been attached due to an error in the corresponding code part.

Comment: I used this reference 
https://literature.cdn.keysight.com/litweb/pdf/54830-97014.pdf?id=595884

Comment: give full path to reach file myscreen.png